# ggplot inserting space before degree symbol on axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to put a degree symbol on the x axis but the result has an extra space that I can't seem to get rid of. The text should read 'Temperature (*C)', not 'Temperature ( *C)'. I've tried two different solutions but can't seem to get rid of the space.

```
ggdat<-data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100))

#neither of these approaches work
xlab <- expression(paste('Temperature (',~degree,'C)',sep=''))
xlab <- expression('Temperature ('*~degree*C*')')

ggplot(data=ggdat,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x=xlab)
```

[image: Scatter plot]

Any help is appreciated!

Ben

Comment: `xlab <- expression("Temperature " ( degree~C))`

Comment: Thanks David_B! Your code got rid of the space in front but for some reason there as a space after the C. But, this worked: `xlab = expression("Temperature " ( degree*C))`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you need your xlabel to be an expression? You could try pasting it in directly. Something like this works:

```
set.seed(1)
ggdat<-data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100))

xlab <- "Temperature (°C)"

ggplot(data=ggdat,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x=xlab)
```

[image]

Comment: Does not seem to work in my (up-to-date) R installation. Probably missing fonts?

Comment: @AF7 It's probably and encoding issue, you could try `Encoding(xlab) <- "latin1"`

Comment: Does not seem to do anything: `Encoding(xlab) <- "latin1"` `xlab
[1] "Temperature ()"` `Encoding(xlab) [1] "unknown"`

Comment: @AF7 Was this working for you before, but is now not working? I believe it's likely an encoding issue, but it's hard to tell without knowing what OS you're using (windows, linux, etc.). It might be helpful if you post a question with a reproducible example since it's difficult to debug without more information. Off the top of my head another option if you are using windows is to do `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")`, but again it would likely be most useful to post a new question

Comment: I'm on Linux, and this has never worked, even when I tried it a couple of years ago. I'll try to find some time to post a question, thnaks

Comment: @AF7 one last thought - that `Sys.setlocale()` that I posted may work for you on linux. Encoding in R can be a nightmare...

Comment: unfortunately it does not look like it works: `Sys.getlocale()                   
[1] "C"` and when I try to change it: `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")     
[1] ""     
Warning message:     
In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English") :     
  OS reports request to set locale to "English" cannot be honored`

Answer (score 14):

When using `expression()` the ~ symbol makes a space and the * symbol sticks things together. See code below:

```
ggdat<-data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100))

ylab <- expression('stuck'*'together'*'eg:'*mu*'liter')
xlab <- expression('sep'~'par'~'at'~'ed'~'eg:'~mu~'liter')

ggplot(data=ggdat,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x=xlab,
       y=ylab)
```

[image: Plot]